# How can I restore power to a circuit after a breaker trip?

Tags: electrical, lighting, ceiling-fan

I was replacing a ceiling fan in my living room. The hot wire arced twice before I was able to figure out the correct circuit breaker to turn off. Now fan/light doesn’t work in either the kitchen or living room. Help? Next step in figuring out to get both working?

Comment: Depending on how the ceiling fan is made(any electronics or fuses) it is possible you burned something out.  A fuse should be a simple replacement.  I am assuming that you did turn on  the right breaker back on after hook up.  It is only the fan/light not working?  All other outlets/lights are still working?

Comment: The correct circuit breaker to turn off is the large one that says "100" or "200".

Comment: @ Harper, How does this give the OP any help?

Answer (score 4):

Check that the breaker hasn't tripped. It most likely has and you need to push the tab all the way to "off" then back to "on" to reset.

If you still have no power to the fans and light, you need to find and reset any GFCI.  The GFCIs can only be rest after the power to them is restored.

Finally if this has not corrected the problem, Check the wiring at the new fan.
(Breaker off first for safety.)  You may have a loose wire or missed connecting a hot or neutral that leads to the other fans.